# Need emacs lisp function to execute command in *shell* buffer

Tags: shell

How to write a function (it would go into .emacs) that sends some command to shell buffer (and initializes shell if needed)?

Something like:

```lisp
(defun ()
  (interactive)
  (shell)
  (sh-send-text "ssh my.server.com"))
```

(I currently do this via tramp and sshx but it is slower than if I manually open shell and just type in the ssh command. So I want to speed this up with a helper function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`comint-send-string` is the function you're looking for.  (`shell` is built on top of the `comint` library.)

It takes a PROCESS and a STRING.  You can get the process from the shell buffer, and conveniently the `shell` function *returns* the buffer, so you can streamline it all into something like:

```el
(defun my-server ()
  "SSH to my.server.com in `shell' buffer."
  (interactive)
  (comint-send-string
   (get-buffer-process (shell))
   "ssh my.server.com\n"))
```

Where the `(shell)` call will take care of creating the shell buffer and/or process if necessary.  (n.b. if there's an existing one, `shell` will re-use that.)

Comment: You might also find it useful to include this so that the `comint` buffer always scrolls to the bottom: `(add-hook 'comint-exec-hook
          (setq comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-output t))`